# Agregar estilo CSS a DATATABLE AJAX

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Cómo puedo agregar estilos CSS (centar columnas, font-size, color etc) a mi DATATABLE y por ejemplo en fecha pago dar otro formato como dd/mm/aaaa cosas de ese estilo

```
function listar() {
  var tablaPagos = $("#payments_table").DataTable({
    ordering:false,
    "destroy":true,
    "ajax":{
      "method":"POST",
      "url":"listar_pagos.php"
    },
    "columns":[
      {"data":"idPago"},
      {"data":"nombreCliente"},
      {"data":"numeroSubcredito"},
      {"data":"campanaProducto"},
      {"data":"tipoPago"},
      {"data":"fechaPago"},
      {"data":"montoPago"},
      {"data":"fechaRegistro"},
      {"defaultContent":"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary none-shadow' 
onClick='eliminarPago(this)'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>"}
    ]
  });
}
```

Aparece de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para el CSS lo puedes aplicar sobre el mismo datatable luego de haberlo llamado, solo haces un CSS propio y ya. Para el formato, dado que es visualizacion, debes usar datatables formatter para mostrar como quieres los datos.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarme como hago eso? Imagine que era desde un fichero css pero como lo aplico ¿?

Comment: Los cambios a estilos CSS se aplican a las clases que crees o quieras modificar. Si una clase tiene X nombre, afectas a esa clase.

Comment: solo agrega  `text-align: center;`  a `table` en tu `css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar datos antes de mostrarse en la tabla, debes usar el parámetro render y una función donde puedes retornar el valor cambiado:

```
function listar() {
  var tablaPagos = $("#payments_table").DataTable({
    ordering:false,
    "destroy":true,
    "ajax":{
      "method":"POST",
      "url":"listar_pagos.php"
    },
    "columns":[
      {"data":"idPago"},
      {"data":"nombreCliente"},
      {"data":"numeroSubcredito"},
      {"data":"campanaProducto"},
      {"data":"tipoPago"},
      {"data":"fechaPago"},
     {"data":"montoPago",
       "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                     
                      return "$"+data+" MXN";
                 }
      },
      {"data":"fechaRegistro"},
      {"defaultContent":"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary none-shadow' 
onClick='eliminarPago(this)'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>"}
    ]
  });
}
```

Para estilizar, puedes hacerlo por columna

```
"columns":[
      {"data":"idPago", "className":"my-class"},
```

O debuggear en opciones de desarrollador y fijarte en las clases que añade Datatable a los elementos HTML, y poner css con esas clases.

Comment: Sería tan amable de colocar un poco más de código por ejemplo para mostrar $1500 MXN, apenas ando aprendiendo jQuery y DataTables

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, revísalo.