# Concatenar text en tabla datatable con AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como concateno texto extra dentro de una tabla que se enlista por AJAX ejemplo tengo el siguiente código que en la columna 7 muestra un valor int que es el monto de pago, pero lo muestra en el front como por ejemplo 1500, necesito que aparezca como "$1500 MXN" ¿Cómo hago eso?
Pense que solo tenía que colocar como:

```
{"data":"montoPago" + "MXN"}, //Por ejemplo

"columns":[
      {"data":"idPago"},
      {"data":"nombreCliente"},
      {"data":"numeroSubcredito"},
      {"data":"campanaProducto"},
      {"data":"tipoPago"},
      {"data":"fechaPago"},
      {"data":"montoPago"},
      {"data":"fechaRegistro"}
    ]
```

Y en caso de fechaPago me regresa 2021-01-01 y otra columna que es fechaRegistro me regresa en formato aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss: en ambas solo quiero formato dd-mm-aaaa ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Investiga sobre `columnDefs`

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida en:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/487426/agregar-estilo-css-a-datatable-ajax/487508#487508